# Redefining a parameter in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm new to verilog and I got a question.

Can I initializing a parameter in global scope and reinitializing it module scope.

```
parameter GLOB_FOO = 5;
module mod2 (in1,clk,out1);
   parameter GLOB_FOO = 7;
   input in1,clk;
   output out1;
   assign out1 = in1;
endmodule
```

In this code I have initialized parameter GLOB_FOO twise in global scope and in module scope.

I looked in the Language Reference Manual as well. But couldn't find the answer since there are a lot of details.

Is This kind of parameter reinitializing is valid in verilog?

Answer (score 1):

You have *re-declared* `GLOB_FOO` inside the module `mod2`, not re-initialized it. That means you have two parameters, one in the compilation unit scope with the value 5, and one in `mod2` with the value 7. The declaration inside `mod2` hides the declaration of the outer compilation unit. `$unit::` can be used to access the outer declaration.

```
parameter GLOB_FOO = 5;
module mod2 (input in1,clk, output out1);
   parameter GLOB_FOO = 7;
   initial begin
         $display(GLOB_FOO); // displays 7
         $display($unit::GLOB_FOO); // displays 5
     end
endmodule
```

You can override the value of the parameters declared inside a module when instantiating it.

```
parameter GLOB_FOO = 5;
module mod2 (input in1,clk, output out1);
   parameter GLOB_FOO = 7;
   initial begin
         $display("%m %d %d", GLOB_FOO, $unit::GLOB_FOO);
endmodule
module top;
  bit A,B, C, CLK;
  mod2 #(3) inst1 (A,CLK,B);
  mod2 #(.GLOB_FOO(4)) inst2 (A,CLK,C);
endmodule
```

This displays

```
#top.inst1           3           5
#top.inst2           4           5
```